# Catel CancelAndCloseView repalced in version 4.3

Tags: mvvm, catel

In Catel 4.3 is the CancelAndCloseViewModel() obsolete.

I have to use the AsynchronousCommand instead.

So
in constructor

```
CmdCancel = new AsynchronousCommand(OnCancel, () => !CmdCancel.IsExecuting)

private void OnCancel
{
  ??????
}
```

Then what?

Kind regards

Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TaskCommand` and use the async methods:

```
var cancelCommand = new TaskCommand(OnCancelExecuteAsync);

public async Task OnCancelExecuteAsync()
{
    await this.CancelAndCloseViewModel();
}
```

Comment: OK. Last command should be await this. CancelAndCloseViewModelAsync() otherwise you still get the error.